# Crear plugin de WordPress que muestre un formulario y con las respuestas del formulario muestre los resultados procesados en otra página

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

estoy realizando un plugin de WordPress, lo estoy creando en el directorio de archivos de Hostinger pero no tengo muchos conocimientos sobre el tema y estoy un poco atascado. Mi objetivo es crear un plugin que muestre un formulario, ese formulario lo rellenará un usuario y las respuestas las quiero procesar mediante un algoritmo de árboles de decisión (tengo pensado usar el lenguaje de python para elaborar dicho algoritmo por lo tanto tendré que buscar la forma de enlazar php con el algoritmo, cosa que tampoco tengo idea de como realizarlo). Una vez el algoritmo haya obtenido los resultados quiero que se muestre en una página (también me gustaría añadir la opción de que se puedan descargar los resultados, aunque supongo que para eso debe de haber algún plugin ya creado que lo realice). Os muestro lo que tengo hecho aunque es muy poco:

---

```php
< ?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Análisis Alimenticio
* Description: Este plugin crea un test dónde un paciente que posea o crea poseer un trastorno alimenticio pueda completarlo y el sistema le mostrará un resultado con posibles trastornos, los cuales podrán ser usados para facilitar la elaboración de una terapia a un psicólogo.
* Author: Fran Zájara Gómez
* Version: 1.0.0
*/


// Definimos el shortcode y la función asociada.

add_shortcode('test_analisis_alimenticio', 'form_analisis');

//Definimos la función

function form_analisis()
{
    
wp_enqueue_style('css_analisisalimenticio', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));
ob_start();


?>

<form action="?page_id=199" method="post">
        <p>Nombre y apellidos:</p>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" required><br>
        
        <p>Edad:</p>
        <input type="number" min="5" max="120" required><br>

        <p>Peso(kilogramos):</p>
        <input type="number" min="20" max="150" required><br>

        <p>Sexo:</p>
        <select name="sexo" required>
            <option value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
            <option value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
        </select>



        <p>Cuestión 1: ¿Sueles ingerir sustancias no alimentarias comunmente?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion1" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion1" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <p>Cuestión 2: Sueles tener ardores o dolores intensos en el estomago?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion2" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion2" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>
        
        <p>Cuestión 3: ¿Sueles expulsar los alimentos una vez masticados?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion3" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion3" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <p>Cuestión 4: ¿Últimamente has sufrido una pérdida de peso significativa?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion4" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion4" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>
        
        <p>Cuestión 5: ¿Sueles evitar ingerir comida debido a su sabor, textura, olor o color?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion5" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion5" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <p>Cuestión 6: ¿En una escala del 1 al 10 cuanto te preocuparía aumentar un poco de peso?</p>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" name="cuestion6" required>

        <p>Cuestión 7: ¿Crees que tu peso actual es normal?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion7" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion7" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <p>Cuestión 8: ¿En los últimos meses has realizado grandes ingestas de comida?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion8" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion8" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <p>Cuestión 9: ¿Te has autoprovocado el vómito o has usado laxantes?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion9" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion9" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <p>Cuestión 10: ¿Frecuentas realizar grandes ingestas de comida?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion10" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion10" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <p>Cuestión 11: ¿Al comer crees que no puedes controlar la cantidad de los alimentos que ingieres?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion11" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion11" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <p>Cuestión 12: ¿En una escala del 1 al 10 cuanto te preocupa tu constitución y peso corporal?</p>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" name="cuestion12" required>

        <p>Cuestión 13: En el caso de que realices grandes ingestas de comida, ¿cuantas veces sueles hacerlo a la semana?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "0" name="cuestion13" value="0" required>
        <label for="0">No realizo grandes ingestas de comida</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "1-3" name="cuestion13" value="1" required>
        <label for="1-3">De 1 a 3 veces por semana</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "4-7" name="cuestion13" value="2" required>
        <label for="4-7">De 4 a 7 veces por semana</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "8-13" name="cuestion13" value="3" required>
        <label for="8-13">De 8 a 13 veces por semana</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "14" name="cuestion13" value="4" required>
        <label for="4">14 o más veces por semana</label>

        <p>Cuestión 14: En el caso de que realices grandes ingestas de comida, selecciona las con cuales de las afirmaciones siguientes estás de acuerdo:</p>
        
        <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14a" value="1" id="check-1">
        <label for="check-1">Como muy rápido</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14b" value="1" id="check-2">
        <label for="check-2">Como aunque no tenga hambre</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14c" value="1" id="check-3">
        <label for="check-3">Al final de comer siento malestar físico</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14d" value="1" id="check-4">
        <label for="check-4">Suelo comer solo, sin que nade me acompañe</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14e" value="1" id="check-5">
        <label for="check-5">Al final de comer me siento deprimido</label><br>
             
        <p>Cuestión 15: ¿Sueles ingerir alimentos por la noche al despertarte del sueño o después de cenar?</p>
        <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion15" value="1" required>
        <label for="si">Sí</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion15" value="0" required>
        <label for="no">No</label>

        <br>
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

< ?php
     
    // Devuelve el contenido del buffer de salida
    return ob_get_clean();
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías crear tu formulario con html y capturar todo con javascript, una vez capturado puedes enviarlo mediante una api a tu algorito de python, phyton procesa esa información y retorna una respuesta, esa respuesta la pintas en wordpress de nuevo, de esa forma usas poco php y casi todo lo manejaria phyton, creo que seria la forma mas simple de hacerlo. luego esa respuesta puedes convertirla en un post para almacenarla, conviertes el post en pdf o cualquier otro formato y listo, claro que tendras que crear la api pero con python no es tan complicado hacerlo.

Comment: Tienes aqui un tutorial. mas o menos explicado  de lo que buscas https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pr73X0WCSlc&list=PLIbWwxXce3Vopq7cfmNGZ340aJL3d4128

Comment: @JefferzonBol Gracias por la respuesta, es interesante el planteamiento, he decidido desarrollar una API en Python con FastAPI y así incluir mi algoritmo dentro, seguramente me salgan algunas dudas por el camino pero creo que lo conseguiré desarrollar.

Comment: @WilfredoAleman Ya le eché un ojo a ese tutorial pero no me consiguió ayudar mucho sobre lo que quiero desarrollar, gracias de todas formas.